# Best way to code Top_Hits aggregation

Tags: nest

Since there is no Top_Hits aggregation in NEST, what is the best way to get around this? I tried looking for an AggregationRaw like there is a QueryRaw, but couldn't find it. What I've done for now is to revert to using the ElasticsearchClient and writting a raw request. I'd prefer to write fluent as much as possible, so something like an AggregationRaw would be best, short of implementing it completely in NEST.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using the low-level `ElasticsearchClient` and writing the request manually is the only way, until it's added to NEST.  You can access the low-level client via the `Raw` property on the high-level `ElasticClient` though, which is a bit cleaner than creating a separate instance:

```
var client = new ElasticClient();
client.Raw.Search("{ \"match_all\" : { } }");
```

The good news is that the `top hits aggregation` is planned to be included in the 1.1 release, which is coming very soon.  Here's a link the GitHub issue so you can keep an eye on it: [#820](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/820).